# What does {0} mean in this Python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following program uses {0} in a string, and I'm not sure how it works, it came up in an online tutorial about iteration for Python, and I can't seem to find anywhere explaining it.

```cpp
import random

number = random.randint(1, 1000)
guesses = 0

print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 1000.")

while True:
   guess = int(input("\nWhat do you think it is? "))
   guesses += 1

    if guess > number:
        print("{0} is too high.".format(guess))
    elif guess < number: 
        print("{0} is too low.".format(guess))
    else:
        break

print("\nCongratulations, you got it in {0} guesses!\n".format(guesses))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 44):

It's an indicator to the format method that you want it to be replaced by the first (index zero) parameter of format. (eg `"2 + 2 = {0}".format(4)`)

Answer (score 23):

It's a boon for placing same arg multiple times

```
print("When you multiply {0} and {1} or {0} and {2}, the result is {0}".format(0,1,2))
```

Isn't this nice!!!

Comment: It's nice, except that when you add 0 to 1, the result is 1, not 0;)

Answer (score 16):

http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

> Perform a string formatting operation. The format_string argument can
>   contain literal text or replacement fields delimited by braces {}.
>   Each replacement field contains either the numeric index of a
>   positional argument, or the name of a keyword argument. Returns a copy
>   of format_string where each replacement field is replaced with the
>   string value of the corresponding argument.

Comment: +1 for linking to the explanation that op couldn't seem to find.

Comment: +1 for linking to the docs that the answer on top (with three times the number of votes!) didn't bother pointing to.

Answer (score 8):

It's a placeholder which will be replaced with the first argument to `format` in the result. `{1}` would be the second argument and so on.

See [Format String Syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) for details.

Answer (score 4):

That is the new python formatting style. Read up on it [here](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax).

Answer (score 2):

```
year = int(input("Enter the year: "))
if year%4 == 0:
    if year%100 == 0:
        if year%400 == 0:
            print("{0} Year is Leap Year".format(year))
        else:
            print("{0} Year is Not Leap Year".format(year))
    else:
        print("{0} Year is Leap Year".format(year))
else:
    print("{0} Year is Not Leap Year".format(year))
```

here I can place the `year` argument in multiple lines using `.format(year)`

output :

```
> Enter the year: 1996
> 1996 Year is Leap Year
```

AND Another example:

```
name = 'sagar'
place = 'hyd'
greet = 'Good'
print("my name is {0}. I am from {1}. Hope everyone doing {2}".format(name,place,greet))
```

output:

```
> my name is sagar.
> I am from hyd. Hope everyone doing Good
```

OR

```
print("my name is {0}. I am from {1}. Hope everyone doing {2}".format('Sagar','Hyd','Good'))
```

Output:

```
> my name is sagar. I am from hyd. Hope everyone doing Good
```